# Change td background color when click on it except its border

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function which changes cell bg color when click on it, but I want to function do nothing when click on cell's border.

```
let table = document.getElementById('table');

table.onclick = function(event) {
  let target = event.target;

  while (target != this) {
    if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
      highlight(target);
      return;
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
}

function highlight(td) {
  td.classList.toggle('purple');
}
```

Comment: Not sure how you will detect it is a border. Guess you could do some x/y check if it is x pixels off the edge of the element.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while` loop? `event.target` is only going to reference one element, so there isn't any collection to loop over. All you need is the `if` statement. If you are interested in making all the `td` elements highlighted, change your initial search to `let cells= document.querySelectorAll('td');` and then loop over the returned collection.

Comment: or just `event.target.closest("td")`

Answer (score 0):

simple: do not put borders on your cells.
use css `border-collapse  : separate`  and `border-spacing: ...`

```js
document.querySelector('#my-table').onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('td')) return
  
  target.classList.toggle('clickinout')
  }
```

```css
body { 
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1em;
  background-color : #2d2d9e;;
  margin           : 2em; 
  }
td {
  border     : none;
  background : whitesmoke;
  padding    : .3em .4em;
  width      : 3em;
  height     : 2em;
  text-align : center;
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
td.clickinout {
  background : #dddd51;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td> a 1 </td><td> a 2 </td><td> a 3 </td><td> a 4 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> b 1 </td><td> b 2 </td><td> b 3 </td><td> b 4 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> c 1 </td><td> c 2 </td><td> c 3 </td><td> c 4 </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```